# Docker Build: Missing Dependency

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

When my Docker build reaches this part of the Dockerfile:

```
    ARG cabal=1.22.9.0
    RUN curl -L http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install-${cabal}/cabal-install-${cabal}.tar.gz | tar -xzf- && \
      cd cabal-install-${cabal} && \
      EXTRA_CONFIGURE_OPTS= ./bootstrap.sh --global
```

It eventually ends with this error.

```
    Downloading zlib-0.6.1.1...
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100  139k    0  139k    0     0   293k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  293k
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Setup.hs, Setup.o )
    Linking Setup ...
    Configuring zlib-0.6.1.1...
    Setup: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
    * Missing (or bad) header file: zlib.h
    * Missing C library: z
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
    If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
    compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
    with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.

    Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
    Configuring the zlib package failed.
    The command '/bin/sh -c curl -L http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install-${cabal}/cabal-install-${cabal}.tar.gz | tar -xzf- &&   cd cabal-install-${cabal} &&   EXTRA_CONFIGURE_OPTS= ./bootstrap.sh --global' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Is there something I can include in my Dockerfile that can prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests?

Comment: I'm really not sure what changes to make in the Dockerfile

Comment: What is your base image? (`FROM ....`)